# Creating navigation properties with custom logic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties, ef-core-3.1

I have one-to-many relation between two models, which is represented implicitly. For example, model A has string column with json-serialized array of ids from model B. So my model A looks like:

```
public class A
{
    [Column("serialized_ids")]
    public string SerializedIds;

    public List<int> DeserializedIds
    {
        get {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(SerializedIds);
        }
    }
}
```

My DBContext includes both models:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> EntitiesA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> EntitiesB { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

What is the best way to create navigation property or something like navigation property in model A to get related `List<B>`?

Comment: Best would be to set up a normal relational table to map to. Other than that, go to the Context's "B" set when you want them from an "A". You'll likely need to mark `DeserializedIds` as `[NotMapped]` or `Ignore` in the mapping.

Comment: Unfortunatellly there is no availability to change anything in database, it's part of task. Can you please explain, how `[NotMapped]` can help with navigation property?

Comment: `[NotMapped]` may be needed on your `List<int>` property as this won't link to any field/relationship in the database. Accessing B's as a property from A isn't really an option. Any possible option to expose them from inside A almost certainly will not be able to be used in a Linq2EF expression such as `.Where(a => a.Bs.Any(b => ...)` EF will simply not be able to compose a query from that without a normalized and mapped data structure. "A" can expose an unmapped property for B Ids, that a context can then use to load applicable Bs, but that would be separate to loading an "A" or A's.